# Issue in using Set Integer (by ref) in Unreal Engine 4.16 blueprint

Tags: unreal, blueprints

I am trying to set the value of an integer by reference in a macro created in my blueprint script. The macro does a simple conditional check of an integer and increments it if it is less than a max value. I was using one of the maze generating tutorials and the function throws a failed to resolve term Value passed into Target error. I am not sure why it cannot deduce the type of Value. The original tutorial was made in UE 4.6, so could it be due to updates made in UE 4.16? I have attached a screenshot of my blueprint.[image]

Comment: Did you find a proper answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use `IncrementInt`:

[image]

It is working in 4.17 as well.